# The Source Attachment Does Not Contain DefaultRequestDirector.class Android

Tags: android, json, apache, httpclient, httpresponse

I am newbie on Android and I am developing an app that connects a php page. However, when I debug my code it gives a `Source not found` Last time it gave it for `DefaulRequestDirector.class`; however, it also gave it for `Abstracthttpclient.class`. I imported the `json` and `apache` packages.

I see that `Source not found` at `HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);` line.

```
 if(method == "POST")
            {
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost); // Source not found
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }
```

LogCat:

```
05-15 16:15:46.133: W/dalvikvm(25727): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415262a0)
05-15 16:15:46.138: E/AndroidRuntime(25727): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-15 16:15:46.138: E/AndroidRuntime(25727): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
05-15 16:15:46.138: E/AndroidRuntime(25727):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1118)
05-15 16:15:46.138: E/AndroidRuntime(25727):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
05-15 16:15:46.138: E/AndroidRuntime(25727):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
05-15 16:15:46.138: E/AndroidRuntime(25727):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
05-15 16:15:46.138: E/AndroidRuntime(25727):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
05-15 16:15:46.138: E/AndroidRuntime(25727):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
05-15 16:15:46.138: E/AndroidRuntime(25727):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
05-15 16:15:46.138: E/AndroidRuntime(25727):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
05-15 16:15:46.138: E/AndroidRuntime(25727):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:670)
05-15 16:15:46.138: E/AndroidRuntime(25727):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:509)
05-15 16:15:46.138: E/AndroidRuntime(25727):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
05-15 16:15:46.138: E/AndroidRuntime(25727):    at com.example.yoritreader.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:59)
05-15 16:15:46.138: E/AndroidRuntime(25727):    at com.example.yoritreader.MainActivity$1.onPreviewFrame(MainActivity.java:246)
05-15 16:15:46.138: E/AndroidRuntime(25727):    at android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java:841)
05-15 16:15:46.138: E/AndroidRuntime(25727):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-15 16:15:46.138: E/AndroidRuntime(25727):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-15 16:15:46.138: E/AndroidRuntime(25727):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
05-15 16:15:46.138: E/AndroidRuntime(25727):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-15 16:15:46.138: E/AndroidRuntime(25727):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-15 16:15:46.138: E/AndroidRuntime(25727):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
05-15 16:15:46.138: E/AndroidRuntime(25727):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
05-15 16:15:46.138: E/AndroidRuntime(25727):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: if(method == "POST") you can not compare string in this way. you should use if (method.equalseIgnoreCase("POST")). Does your app crash? If it so post the logcat

Comment: Yeah but I do not think string comparison causes this. In debug mode, it only gives some D level messages. But I added runtime E level messages of LogCat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

you are getting the `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. It means that your are performing blocking operation, such as operations that involve the network, on the UI THread. This behaviour have been always deeply discorauged but since Android 3.0 it has been forbidden. So you should move your code on AsyncTask.

Also, in Java, String comparison can not be performed with `==` operator.

```
if(method == "POST")
```

this is wrong. You should use

```
string1.equals(string2)
```

or `string1.equalsIgnoreCase(string2)`

You can read this [guide](http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2009/05/painless-threading.html) for Thread/AsyncTask

Comment: I got it. Thanks for the advice. I hope it solves the problem!